# facebookOGPをCakePHPで使う際に他のprefixも使いたい

Tags: cakephp

https://github.com/monsat/Ogp

を使っているのですが、

/View/Helper/OgpHelper.php
を編集して
`fb:admins`、`fb:app_id`、`article:publisher`を設定したいのですがどのようにすれば良いのかいまいち分かりません。

どなたかtipを頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんにちは。
プラグインを作成した者です。
と言っても、こちら、PullRequestをいただき実装した機能であり、かつ、最近触ってないので、TestCaseを見て回答します。

https://github.com/monsat/Ogp/blob/master/Test/Case/View/Helper/OgpHelperTest.php#L135

にある通り

```
$this->Ogp->set('ipp_id', '1234567890', array('prefix' => 'fb:'));
```

とすると

```
<meta property="fb:ipp_id" content="1234567890" />
```

このように表示されます。

いかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答いただきまして有難うございました。
無事にこちら表示されていましたのでご連絡いたします。